# Identifying which points belong to which part of the Multipolygon after extracting vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, multipart, multi-polygon

I currently have a layer which is composed of different areas. I want to extract the coordinates of the vertices of the shape to CSV in QGIS, which I successfully am able to do by using extract vertices. What I also wanted to do is to know which vertices belong to which "sub-area", as exemplified in the picture below by the numbers, so I'd be able to indicate in the CSV which point belongs to "1", which ones to "2" and so on.

I tried using "multiparts to singleparts". My logic was if I could divide the shape in different parts I could use "extract vertices" on each one of them and retrieve each area points. However, the shape returned remains the same, as one. So I'm not sure what I can do here. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Comment: please describe how you used Multipart to Single Part as the polygon should not remain the same

Comment: Hi Ian, basically by selecting the function in Vector->Geometry Tools->Multiparts to Singleparts, selecting the polygon in the dropdown list and pressing Run. The output is the same just in another color.

Comment: Well if you colour all the polygons the same colour you will see the same thing. Try selecting one of the polygons

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, but maybe it has something to do with what I just found out. If I use the Singleparts and then Toggle Editing -> Vertex Tool - Current Layer, I'm able to right click the singular polygons and see the coordinates in a window that opens called "Vertex Editor". From there I can just copy and paste the data somewhere else.
Also did some testing with MMQGIS and by exporting the original geometry to CSV the export already divides the data in a column called "partid" which is also great.
Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices) geoalgorithm creates the `"vertex_part_ring"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in the field expression calculator for the verticies:

```
overlay_nearest('MultiPolygon', $id)[0]
```

That would add a field with the ID of the polygon to your points / verticies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have polygon layer and point layer you can use join attribute by location and make sure you have select intersect